# Generalized Euler sequence on a projective scheme

Tags: kahler-differentials, ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-morphisms, reference-request

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on a scheme $S$. Consider the projective scheme $p : \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) \to S$ and the canonical epimorphism $p^*(\mathcal{E}) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)$. This corresponds to an epimorphism $p^*(\mathcal{E})(-1) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}$. It is well-known that its kernel is isomorphic to $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}/S}$ if $S$ is affine and $\mathcal{E}$ is free of finite rank (Hartshorne, Theorem II.8.13): This is the famous *Euler sequence*.  This also follows when $S$ is arbitrary and $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free of finite rank. Even for that I don't know a reference in the literature, except for Ravi Vakil's notes, Class 39.

Actually, I have proven that it holds without any assumptions on $\mathcal{E}$, i.e. we always have an exact sequence $0 \to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}/S} \to p^*(\mathcal{E})(-1) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}} \to 0$ (*generalized Euler sequence*). The proof takes two pages, but basically it is a direct coordinate-free generalization of the proof of the special case already mentioned. I don't want to put so much spam in my thesis, and would like to cite this result, which probably has been proven in the 60s. I could not find it in EGA. So my question is: Is this already written down somewhere?

*Edit*: This Euler sequence can be now found in my [thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1716) as Theorem 4.5.13. I still wonder if there is another reference.

Comment: I'm not sure though, but I don't think such an exact sequence can hold if $\mathcal E$ is not coherent (or at least if $\mathcal E$ is free of infinite rank).

Comment: @Mike: I am pretty sure that the usual proof works for $\mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus I}$, where $I$ is any set. Locally, one uses that $\Omega^1_{R[\{x_i\}_{i \in I}]/R}$ is free on $\{d(x_i) : i \in I\}$. It follows that the sequence is exact when $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free (without any restriction on the rank).

Comment: *I don't want to put so much spam in my thesis, and would like to cite this result, which probably has been proven in the 60s* Giving appropriate credit is nice and important of course. Then again, a thesis seems to me to be a good place to write up things that are supposedly well-known to the experts but for which a good reference is lacking.

Comment: I completely agree with Olivier.

Comment: Is this generalized Euler sequence well-known to the experts?

Comment: I agree with Olivier.  If you use the phrasing "the following is undoubtedly well-known to the experts, but the author was unable to find it in the literature.  For completeness, we give a proof."  My personal reading of this is that very possibly you are the first person to give a proof in the literature, and you are doing a great service, without offending those would cry out "but this is well known!"